# Website I want to test shows "no internet connection" ONLY while recording through jmeter although proxy has been set correctly

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

The website I want to test shows "no internet connection" ONLY while recording through jmeter test script recorder. Normally the website works fine but as soon as I click on start recording, a pop up comes up that says "no internet connection". I have recorded scripts on other sites using jmeter and it works fine. This issue comes up ONLY for this particular site I am testing. Could you please help me find out why is it happening? PL. refer attached images.

[Image 1 - when jmeter proxy set and recording begins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ormzu.jpg)

[Image 2 -  normally website opens without any proxy/jmeter recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxv1H.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case you're using the proxy server in your browser for connecting to the Internet.

And when you substitute the proxy server which gives you the Internet access with JMeter's proxy - you will be able to access local resources only.

The solution would be [making JMeter aware of the upstream proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) server by providing the proxy details via command-line arguments like:

jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000

These changes can also be made permanent if you put the following lines to [system.properties file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/):

```
http.proxyHost=my.proxy.server
http.proxyPort=8080
https.proxyHost=my.proxy.server
https.proxyPort=8080
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. I have tried adding the changes you mentioned into the system.properties file

Comment: but the browser now asks me to login to my network provided in order to continue accessing internet. When I click on "connect" it shows this error msg in browser - Pl. take a look at this scrrenshot . Hi, thank you for responding. I have tried adding the changes you mentioned into the system.properties file(even mentioned the same proxy port no. to be used) ...but the browser now asks me to login to my network provided in order to continue accessing internet. When I click on "connect" it shows this error msg in browser - Please take a lookaat the screenshot I have taken. https://ibb.co/wSH7cQ0

Comment: https://ibb.co/Sycz9xb

Comment: Your description is too vague hence I cannot come up with a comprehensive solution. The error you're getting means that JMeter cannot get the IP address of the website using [IPv6 protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6), maybe if your network infrastructure is not IPv6 ready yet you can "tell" JMeter to use IPv4 by [running JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) as `jmeter -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx`. If it helps - you can set the property in the aforementioned *system.properties* file.

Comment: Okayyy.. il follow like you said ...thank you :)